# How to add multiple classes, one with incrementing numbers, on a dynamic element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, swiper.js

i've been trying to create some slides using swipe slider with custom classes.

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    }
});
</script>
```

The swipe pagination is dynamically created and generates into

```
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">1</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">2</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">3</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">4</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">5</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">6</span>
```

I want to have the div class swiper pagination into

```
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet color-0">1</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet color-1">2</span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet color-2">3</span>
```

How do I add an additional custom class of color-0, color-1, color-2? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return '<span class="'+ className +' color-'+index+'" >'+(index+1)+'</span>';
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much ! I've been trying to solve this for like 3 hours.

Comment: Great! There are a few ways to do this. but per your code this was easiest. You can always add more than one class to dynamically created elements. Please mark this as the accepted answer for me and the community if it answers your question :)